# If second two characters equal this then that

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a string of letters and numbers, where if the second two characters of the string equal a certain value, then a location value should be shown in the corresponding column.

I have used the `MID` function to essentially extract the characters of the string that I want to use `MID(A2,2,2)` but now I can't figure out how to compare what is returned to a list of options that those two characters could be without typing in each option in an extremely long formula.

Here are possible strings that are situated in a column:

```
3PH356969   
MSFFACEBUS   
MBH0007398   
MBH0007402
```

I am extracting the second two characters of these, to compare to a list similar to this

```
PH  
SF  
BH  
PG  
HR
```

These values then correspond to location (below), which would optimally be returned:

```
Philadelphia   
Bay Area    
Birmingham   
Western PA   
Hartford
```

I can write `=IF(MID(A2,2,2)="PH","Philadelphia",else...)` but then the else-ifs will go on for 76 more  2-character strings to compare against. I'm hoping there is a more optimal way for this.

Expected results should be the location corresponding to the string, or just "error" displayed.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the fast responses! Solved thanks to answers.

Answer (score 3):

Basically we need to use a lookup/reference table, but instead of a much more common `VLOOKUP` function we can use a much faster `INDEX` + `MATCH` combo.

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=INDEX($E$1:$E$6,MATCH(MID(A1,2,2),$D$1:$D$6;0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a VLOOKUP, personally. Although it would require a separate lookup table, just feed your MID result as the VLOOKUP key. Then you could easily add/remove locations, and there will be an #N/A error if the key's not there.

Comment: agree that using `VLOOKUP` is far preferable to hard-coding codes in your formula. And a helper column might come in handy here as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a separate lookup table, you may try it this way:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"Philadelphia","Bay Area","Birmingham","Western PA","Hartford"},MATCH(MID(A2,2,2),{"PH","SF","BH","PG","HR"},0)),"Not found")
```